# How to set pydantic model minimum size

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a pydantic model below:

```
class model(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] 
    age: Optional[int]
    gender: Optional[str]
```

and validating the request body using this model. but want to set minimum size of pydantic model to be 1 so endpoint should not process empty input

```
@app.post("my_url")
def test(req: dict=model):
    some code
```

can use length function inside body but trying to find some pydantic way.
Please help !

Comment: *want to set minimum size of pydantic model to be 1* Can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: as we use min_items=1 for field attributes in a model.
need something similar so that model should give pydantic error if no attributes are given

Comment: Can you please give an example where the validation should fail and why?

Comment: Maybe you can add an __init__ method to the class?

Comment: What you want is a [root validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#root-validators) checking that at least one value is not `None`.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward solution is a [root validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#root-validators) as mentionend by M.O. in the comments above:

```py
from typing import Any, Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class Model(BaseModel):
    foo: Optional[str]
    bar: Optional[int]
    baz: Optional[float]

    @root_validator
    def ensure_one_field_is_set(cls, data: dict[str, Any]) -> dict[str, Any]:
        if all(value is None for value in data.values()):
            raise ValueError("At least one value must be provided")
        return data
```

Demo:

```py
from pydantic import ValidationError


print(Model(bar=69).json(indent=4))
try:
    Model()
except ValidationError as err:
    print(err.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "foo": null,
    "bar": 69,
    "baz": null
}
```

```json
[
    {
        "loc": [
            "__root__"
        ],
        "msg": "At least one value must be provided",
        "type": "value_error"
    }
]
```

---

However there is one potential pitfall with this approach.

Root validators are called in the order they were *registered* with model. This means, if you subclass `Model` and add a new root validator that sets one of the fields to not-`None`, the previous root validator will still be called first and it will raise an error before the new validator gets a chance to intervene:

```py
class SubModel(Model):
    @root_validator
    def set_baz_if_all_are_none(cls, data: dict[str, Any]) -> dict[str, Any]:
        if all(value is None for value in data.values()):
            data["baz"] = 3.14
        return data

SubModel()  # will cause an error, `baz` will not be set
```

Granted, this is a contrived example, but still something to keep in mind. You can work around this by explicitly *overriding* the previous validator method:

```py
class SubModel(Model):
    @root_validator
    def set_baz_if_all_are_none(cls, data: dict[str, Any]) -> dict[str, Any]:
        if all(value is None for value in data.values()):
            data["baz"] = 3.14
        return data

    @root_validator
    def ensure_one_field_is_set(cls, data: dict[str, Any]) -> dict[str, Any]:
        return data  # do nothing


print(SubModel())  # foo=None bar=None baz=3.14
```

---

An alternative would be to simply do the check in your own `__init__` method and manually construct a `ValidationError`:

```py
from typing import Any, Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError
from pydantic.error_wrappers import ErrorWrapper


class Model(BaseModel):
    foo: Optional[str]
    bar: Optional[int]
    baz: Optional[float]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if all(value is None for _field, value in self):
            raise ValidationError(
                [
                    ErrorWrapper(
                        ValueError("At least one value must be provided"),
                        "__root__",
                    )
                ],
                self.__class__,
            )
```

Doing `Model()` would now produce the same error as with the root validator above.